# How to think of thread-safe code in below case? I'm new to this and need suggestion as to how should I proceed

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

This is an assignment so I do not expect a direct answer and request to refrain from solving it for me. Some hint which might help me think of the solution would be really appreciated.

```
/**
* Implementations of this interface and access to shared data must be thread-safe.
**/

public interface InventoryManagementSystem {
    /**
    * Deduct 'amountToPick' of the given 'productId' from inventory.
    * @param productId The ID of the product to pick
    * @param amountToPick The quantity of the product to pick
    * @return TODO: to be implemented
    */
    PickingResult pickProduct(String productId, int amountToPick);
    /**
    * Add 'amountToRestock' of the given productId to inventory.
    * @param productId The ID of the product to restock
    * @param amountToRestock The quantity of the product to restock
    * @return TODO: to be implemented
    */
    RestockingResult restockProduct(String productId, int amountToRestock);
}
```

NOTE: Cannot use/import any external modules other than JDK stuff.

Comment: This really isn't a lot to run with. What does picking a product do? Restocking a product do? This might be better-received if you can isolate where you'd like a hint.

Comment: I think the assignment is to *implement* these methods. See TODO comments. Interfaces cannot be made thread-safe, only implementations can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most critical concept for thread safety is that synchronization needs to happen around *data*, not *code*. Whenever you access data from two threads, and one or both of the threads modify the data, you have the potential to create problems.

So I'm assuming the two methods `pickProduct` and `restockProduct` will access some local datastructure from multiple threads, and hence the need to synchronize the access. The most straight-forward hint I can give you is to use the [synchronized](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) keyword, locking the data object, so that only one thread can read or write to it at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by looking up definitions of thread-safe.
I would then start looking to see what mechanisms I might use for thread safety.

I would also have a look in the JDK itself for examples of thread-safe classes and see how they have done it.

Personally, I would start looking towards limiting preventing the use of shared state.